# $P(B|A)\geq 1-\frac{P(B')}{P(A)}$ if $P(A)>0$ and $P(A)+P(B)>1$

Tags: probability, inequality, conditional-probability

> If A and B are two events such that $P(A)>0$ and $P(A)+P(B)>1$, then my reference says the following statement is false : $P(B|A)\geq 1-\frac{P(B')}{P(A)}$

**My Attempt**
$$
P(B|A)\geq 1-\frac{P(B')}{P(A)}\implies\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)}\geq\frac{P(A)-1+P(B)}{P(A)}\\
\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)}\geq\frac{P(A)+P(B)-1}{P(A)}\implies \frac{P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cup B)}{P(A)}\geq\frac{P(A)+P(B)-1}{P(A)}\\
P(A\cup B)\leq 1\;\text{ which is true}
$$
What is really going wrong here ?

Here is the snapshot: [image]

Comment: I think you are right!

Comment: Working with inequalities in this way can be risky, but I don't think you made any mistakes.  Everything is reversible...I agree with your conclusion.

Comment: The reference seems to be wrong. Could you provide us the exact quote?

Comment: @JaroslawMatlak not a very reputable one. I have added a snapshot of solution found.

Comment: What reference are you citing?

Comment: @lulu i did not mention the reference bcz it s not a reputable one, could find mistakes sometimes. I added the snapshot at the request of JaroslawMatlak for the exact quote.

Comment: Oh, no problem.  But I'd advise getting a better reference.  Good work on your solution!

Comment: @lulu u welcome and thanx for the help.

Comment: It looks more like a question of type "Is it true or false?" rather than a theorem or lemma.